# Request method 'GET' not supported Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm a beginer full stack developer. I need help.

I have the following code:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
@Autowired
private MessageRepos messageRepos;

@GetMapping("/")
public String greeting(Map<String, Object> model) {
    return "greeting";
}

@GetMapping("/main")
public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepos.findAll();
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}

@PostMapping("/main")
public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Message message = new Message(text, tag);
    messageRepos.save(message);
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepos.findAll();
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}
@PostMapping("filter")
public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Iterable<Message> messages;
    if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
        messages = messageRepos.findByTag(filter);
    } else {
        messages = messageRepos.findAll();
    }
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
</div>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Message" />
        <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Tag">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="filter">
        <input type="text" name="filter">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I click on the buttons **add** and **find** I get the problem.

**Problem:**

> Request method 'GET' not supported.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the complete but minimal code sample that illustrates your problem. Specifically, include a complete class of the controller but only the method mapping you have issues with. Also clarify where exactly the error happens (e.g. in the browser, in server logs etc.). HTTP API could be tested without browser (e.g. with curl). Try to figure out if the problem is on the client or on the server, this will reduce the scope of the question and will help you to get an answer faster.

Comment: Also, the tags `sping-boot` and `spring-security` don't seem to be relevant for the question.